# SQL Agent Job is not updating the schedule from weekly to daily

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job

Following is SQL Agent Job that was initially created. Later the requirement was to change it from weekly to daily process. So I updated the scheduler for the job. It executed successfully and updated the SQL Agent Job but the Job didn't triggered on time.
I played around it and found that updating scheduler didn't updated the schedule of the job.

I have updated some code because I don't have permission to post real code. My apologies.

```
USE [msdb]
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'Test for SAJ', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'No description available.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'LocalUser', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Test Step', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'EXEC [msdb].dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name=''SQL Mail Agent'',
@recipients=''someone@email.com'',
@subject=''SAJ - Schedular test'',
@body=''Ignore''', 
        @database_name=N'MyDatabase', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'Real test', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=8,  ------------------------------------> Weekly process
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=1, 
        @freq_subday_interval=0, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=1, -----------------------> Once on Sunday
        @active_start_date=20200427, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=0, 
        @active_end_time=235959, 
        @schedule_uid=N'<GUID for Schedule>'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:
GO
```

I used following script to update SQL Agent Job's schedule:

```
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@JobId, @name=N'Real test', 
            @enabled=1, 
            @freq_type=4,  ------------------------------------> Daily process
            @freq_interval=1, 
            @freq_subday_type=1, 
            @freq_subday_interval=0,
            @freq_relative_interval=0,
            @freq_recurrence_factor=0, -----------------------> Not used for Daily freq_type, so 0
            @active_start_date=20200427,
            @active_end_date=99991231,
            @active_start_time=10000,
            @active_end_time=235959,
            @schedule_uid=N'<GUID for Schedule>'
```

Today is 04/27/2020. The next_run_date for the following query was `20200503` which would be correct date if this was weekly process. And this means it is still scheduled for weekly and haven't updated to trigger daily. I believe that correct answer should be `20200428`.

```
SELECT next_run_date 
FROM dbo.sysjobschedules
WHERE job_id = '<GUID for Job>'
```

Result:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
schedule_id | job_id         | next_run_date | next_run_time|
------------------------------------------------------------
1234        | <GUID for Job> | 20200503      | 0            |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to update it using GUI and that works perfectly. But I want to update this with script only.
**How can I update this to trigger it daily using script?**

Comment: Have you tried scripting the job from the SSMS GUI and comparing that output against your own SQL code?

Comment: Alternatively, have you tried making the change in SSMS and then, instead of saving, hitting the little "Script" button at the top of the window?

Comment: For both of these I am getting Script same as when I right click on SQL Agent Job >> Script Job as >> CREATE To >> New Query Editor Window. and arrow-ed line are the only difference. "Script" button was new learning for me, Thanks @BenThul